# Using template-name in place of template-id inside class template definition

Tags: c++, templates

Is the following C++ code correct? And if so, could anybody point me to a paragraph in the standard that mentions this? It seems that one can use template-name instead of template-id in a scope enclosed with template and the compiler automatically adds the template argument list.

```
template<class Type>
class Mana {
public:
  Mana(const Mana& m) {/*...*/}
  Mana() {/*...*/}
};
```

as opposed to:

```
template<class Type>
class Mana {
public:
  Mana(const Mana<Type>& m) {/*...*/}
  Mana() {/*...*/}
};
```

The code compiles with g++ as well as in MS visual studio.

Comment: The code is correct. `Mana` is equivalent to `Mana<Type>`. For quote from standard, we need to wait.

Answer (score 7):

Yes the code is correct. (The quote: §14.6.1[temp.local]/2

> Within the scope of a class template specialization or partial specialization, when the *injected-class-name* is
>   used as a *type-name*, it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-arguments* of the class
>   template specialization or partial specialization enclosed in `<>`. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<template<class> class T> class A { };
> template<class T> class Y;
> template<> class Y<int> {
>    Y* p;        // meaning Y<int>
>    Y<char>* q;  // meaning Y<char>
>    A<Y>* a;     // meaning A<::Y>
>    class B {
>        template<class> friend class Y;   // meaning ::Y
>    };
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

)

In fact this is used all over the place in the standard as well, e.g.

```
// §20.4.2.1[tuple.cnstr]/10-13
tuple(const tuple& u) = default;
tuple(tuple&& u) = default;

// §21.4.6.1[string::op+=]/1-2
basic_string& operator+=(const basic_string& str);

// etc.
```